# C# .Rows and .Cells doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using a ASP.NET GridView and now I want to define the colspan automatically.
I had th VB code and I converted it to C#. My code is currently looking like that, but the .Cells and .Rows aren't working. Does anyone know what's wrong. Am I not allowed to use these?
+ I found the right namespace: System.Windows.Forms
 but then I also need to use 
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCollection; but where do I put it?

```
 protected void grdvCamp_DataBound1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int rowIndex = grdvCamp.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex += -1)
    {
        GridViewRow gvRow = grdvCamp.Rows(rowIndex);
        GridViewRow gvPreviousRow = grdvCamp.Rows(rowIndex + 1);
        for (int cellCount = 0; cellCount <= gvRow.Cells.Count - 9; cellCount++)
        {
            if (gvRow.Cells(cellCount).Text == gvPreviousRow.Cells(cellCount).Text)
            {
                if (gvPreviousRow.Cells(cellCount).RowSpan < 2)
                {
                    gvRow.Cells(cellCount).RowSpan = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    gvRow.Cells(cellCount).RowSpan = gvPreviousRow.Cells(cellCount).RowSpan + 1;
                }
                gvPreviousRow.Cells(cellCount).Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms` but tagged with ASP.NET? _"The .Cells and .Rows aren't working. Does anyone know what's wrong"_ What is not working, do you get an error? If so, _what_
 error do you get?

Comment: "aren't working" is spectacularly vague. What *exactly* are you seeing? Note that you appear to be trying to use `Cells` as if it's a method. Perhaps you wanted `Cells[cellCount]` instead of `Cells(cellcount)`?

Comment: So it says "System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.Rows" can't be used like a method

Comment: `Rows` is a property, not a method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the right syntax should be

```
.Rows[rowIndex]
.Cells[cellCount]
```

instead of

```
.Rows(rowIndex)
.Cells(cellCount)
```

since both returns a collection. As far as I know, `()` syntax uses in vb.net but `[]` uses in C#. When you write `grdvCamp.Rows(rowIndex)` in C#, it looks `Rows` as a method of `grdvCamp`, not a collection.

For more information;

- [`GridView.Rows` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`TableRows.Cells` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerow.cells%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Worked like that, because I used a converter it didn't change that

Comment: @fusionchart_help If I were you, I wouldn't trust a converter to successfully conversation to my all code. After all, they made by human, too. Best way to convert is learning both language (at least the syntax of data structure visualization) and **do it yourself**.